# Differences between easier,medium, and hard difficulties

Tags: hammerwatch

What is different between the different difficulty levels? How does it get harder?

Comment: I know on Hard, the enemies move twice as fast. That's all I know for now though!

Comment: This is an extremely light amount of content in a question.

Comment: @Scribblenautical sure it is short, but is it not clear? Would you rather me fill the question with unnecessary fluff to bring up the word count?

Comment: @Scribblenautical What else do you suggest Colin should add to the question? As it stands right now, the question is satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing difficulty has the following effects:

- Increased enemy health
- Increased enemy damage
- Increased enemy move speed
- Increased enemy spawn rate
- Decreased coin value of money pickups

[Source: a steam discussion where one of the developers posted config file values](http://steamcommunity.com/app/239070/discussions/0/540744934270449737/])